# Breakpoints in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++

I am using an old compiler for a project (Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 (1998)) and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically place breakpoints in every function of a .c file, or if there is a shortcut for jumping to the next declared function if you debugging or looking at the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically, or asking how to use an IDE?

Comment: IDE, I thought I remembered seeing something about how you can shortcut toggle from one function to the next?

Comment: I guess either would work

Answer (score 0):

**To set a break point, position the cursor at the desired place and press F9 (or use Right-mouse-button | Insert/Remove Breakpoint).**

**Summary of Key Commands**

```
F5      Start program execution, run until a breakpoint is reached.
Shift-F5        Stop debugging and return to program edit mode.
Ctrl-Shift-F5       Restart the program in debugging mode.
F9      Insert, disable or remove a breakpoint.
Shift-F9        Get the value of a variable.
F10     Execute the current statement or function call.
Ctrl-F10        Run the program to the point where the cursor is.
F11     If the current statement is a function call, step into the function.
Shift-F11       If executing a function, run to the end and return to the calling statement.
```

Comment: I know all of the debugging basic shortcut keys, I was asking if there is a way to jump from function to function, or to automatically insert a breakpoint in every function in a .c file

Answer (score 0):

You can break on every function of a specific class by adding a new break point (Debug->New Break Point) and writing something like CMyClass::*

Related post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger.aspx

I think this should work in VS6